# When will an async await method return from the UI-Thread? At the first await or at the inner await?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I am using async await in WPF on the UI-Thread. I have a question on how async await works in a certain scenario. I will try to explain it on an example.

### Background

Let's assume I have the Button A with click event handler `ButtonA_Click()` and Button B with `ButtonB_Click()`.  The click handlers will check if the `RunLoop()` method is still running. If it is not running, they start `RunLoop()`.

### Question:

1. Will the event handler return from the UI-Thread when (the outer) `await RunLoop()` is called?
2. Or will it return at the (inner) await in `RunLoop()` because there is synchronous code (`_isStopped = false;`) it could perform in the beginning of `Runloop()`.

If 1. is true, it could cause a racing condition, or? When both click handlers are called at the same time, they will run right after each other on the UI-Thread. So the second event handler may run before RunLoop() can be executed for the first time.  In this case _isStopped would still be false for the 2nd event handler and it would start a `RunLoop()`, too. Thus 2 `RunLoop()` would be active. Is that correct?

(PS: I know, that if 1. is the case, I can solve this by putting `_isStopped = false` into the click handlers, but this question is more about understanding how async await works when the methods are nested this way).

### Code

```
private bool _isStopped = true;
private List<Customer> _customers;  // will be filled from somewhere else

public async void ButtonA_Click()
{
    // do some stuff synchronously

    if (_isStopped)
        await RunLoop();
}

public async void ButtonB_Click()
{
    // do some stuff synchronously

    if (_isStopped)
        await RunLoop();
}

private async Task RunLoop()
{
    _isStopped = false;

    while (_customers.Any())
    {
        _customers.Remove(...);
        await Task.Run(() => ProcessStuff());
    }        

    _isStopped = true;
}
```

### Update after getting the answers:

those links helped me to understand it better

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/control-flow-in-async-programs

Comment: Are you aware that the `List<Customer> _customers` is not thread-safe, and it is accessed by multiple threads concurrently without synchronization?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias good point. It could be accessed by 2 Threads. This is a simplified version of the problem I had. I see I made a mistake when creating this version. The customer is actually removed in the while loop above Task.Run() and not in ProcessStuff(). But that doesnt change the real question.

Comment: I was going to suggest that. As long as you access and manipulate the `List` exclusively from the UI thread, there will be no thread-safety problem whatsoever. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Control returns to the calling method when `await` is given an *incomplete* `Task`.

That means that first, `await` has to be given a `Task`, which means the method you called has to return before `await` does anything. And second, the `Task` has to be incomplete. If `await` sees a complete `Task`, execution resumes synchronously.

In your case, lets say `ButtonA_Click()` runs:

1. `ButtonA_Click()` starts running synchronously.
2. `RunLoop()` is executed, which starts running synchronously.
3. `Task.Run` is executed, which will return an incomplete `Task`.
4. The `await` in `RunLoop()` sees that incomplete `Task` and returns its own incomplete `Task`.
5. The `await` in `ButtonA_Click()` sees that incomplete `Task` and would normally return a `Task`, but the method is `void`, so it returns nothing.
6. Control is passed to whatever called `ButtonA_Click()`.

Microsoft has some well-written articles on [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index) that are worth the read.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I read this articel and many others a week before. It is a good articel, but this case wasnt clear to me after reading it. but I just found out... that it has multiple pages in the navigation on the left. I gonna check the rest now. I think this one is handling the topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/control-flow-in-async-programs

Answer (score 2):

It's gonna be the second option. Code in an `async` method runs synchronously until it encounters an `await` statement awaiting a non-completed `Task`.

Note that it might run synchronously all the way if all awaited `Tasks` are finished before being awaited, or if none of the code actually needs an `await` statement.